# Python - Threading.thread returning "None" after calling a method that has values

Tags: python, multithreading

So what I am trying to do is that I have a loop etc

```
for values in list:
```

where every values has different list which is pretty understandable. However I want to mix it up with threading. I want that every **values** should be runned by a thread.

I want to show you my code that I have coded:

```
def get_info(thread):


    json_resp = json.loads(thread) #could be whatever here, Just took an example

    name = json_resp['name']
    year = json_resp['year']

    metadata = {
        'name': name,
        'year': year
    }

    return metadata #returning the value of metadata



def script():

    old_list = []
    new_list = [1,2,3,4,5] #Just a random new_list made.
    while True:
        for thread in new_list:
            test = threading.Thread(target=get_info, args=(thread,)).start() #Issue here

            if test in old_list:
               old_list.append(test)
```

The issue I am having is that if I print out test like this

```
for thread in new_list:
     test = threading.Thread(target=get_info, args=(thread,)).start() #Issue here
     print(test)
```

it is just returning None when it supposed to return the metadata.

---

So what I want to try to do is that every thread in the for loop `for thread in new_list:` is that I want to create a *threading.Thread* where it later returns the value of metadata and then checks if it fits `if test in old_list:` or not. If it fits then it will continue and if not then it should just sleep x seconds and retry the process again.

---

edit:

```
thr = threading.Thread(target=get_info, args=(thread,))
thr.start()
thr.join()
print(thr)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems here, though all are really aspects of a single fundamental misunderstanding.

First, `threading.Thread` is actually a class, so calling `threading.Thread` produces an instance of one of these classes.  You should save the result in a variable:

```
thr = threading.Thread(target=get_info, args=(thread,))
```

Next, the `start` operation of any thread instance simply invokes the `run` function.  The default `run` function calls your `target` function with your `args`:

```
def run(self):
    """Method representing the thread's activity.

    You may override this method in a subclass. The standard run() method
    invokes the callable object passed to the object's constructor as the
    target argument, if any, with sequential and keyword arguments taken
    from the args and kwargs arguments, respectively.

    """
    try:
        if self.__target:
            self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
    finally:
        # Avoid a refcycle if the thread is running a function with
        # an argument that has a member that points to the thread.
        del self.__target, self.__args, self.__kwargs
```

Note that there is no return value from `run`, and hence there is no return value from `start` either.

To wait for a thread to finish, you must call its `join`:

```
thr.join()
```

This waits (for an optional timeout, if given; by default, forever) for the thread to terminate.  Returning from the `run` function causes the thread to terminate, so if the function you told the default `run` to call returns—with or without any return value; `run` will throw away any return value—the thread terminates.

The fundamental issue, then, is that you need to have your threads put values somewhere that other threads—including your main program—can *use* them.  There are different places you may choose to put them.  One way to deal with this is to define *your own class*, derived from `threading.Thread`:

```
class Foo(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        self.value = get_info(...)
```

Now you don't need to pass a `target` and `args` (though you can if you want).  The caller can spin off several threads:

```
threads=[]
# spin off five threads
for i in range(5):
    t = Foo()
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
# now wait for all 5 threads:
for i in range(5):
    threads[i].join()
# and all our return values are now in threads[i].value
```

(There are many other ways to construct this, but that's a simple enough example.)

Comment: Oh lord that was quite alot of information here I would say! It was very helpful but I still can't understand really how, or atleast some stuff of it. I mean using threads is a huge thing and is very complicated. But what I tried as you did in your first sentence where you say to name to `thr = threading.Thread(target=get_info, args=(thread,))` which I did, Whenever I print it though it tells me `<Thread(Thread-2, stopped 1580)>` whenever I am trying to get the value back... I edited in my thread what I did.

Comment: It *is* pretty complex. Threads are powerful and full of sharp edges, like juggling running chainsaws. :-) If you print a thread instance like `thr`, you'll get information about the class object that describes the thread. The "stopped" means it has has finished, i.e., it's all done and `thr.join()` will return immediately. (Fixed—I originally said "not yet started" but that shows up as "initial", not "stopped".)

Comment: Oh yeah. It is really good I would say but I do call it. If you check my edit at the bottom. You will see what I did :) But I assume that way will still not work getting information from another method? Or it maybe doesn't even supposed to give a value back from `get_info` ?

Comment: There's a terminology issue here: `get_info` is not a method. A method is a function defined inside a class, so with `class Foo(threading.Thread)`, the functions defined inside this class—`def run(self):` for example—are methods. Your `get_info` is not a method, it's plain function. Functions just return values; the caller, whoever that is, has to do something with the value. The default methods in the `Thread` class throw them away, so obviously those class-methods are not suitable for this kind of use.

Comment: You *could* define your function such that it saves its "return value" in a global variable. However, if you *do* do this, you have a different problem, namely: now you have multiple threads, each trying to write to a single shared global variable. How do you plan to deal with this problem? (There are ways to do it, which is why threads are such a big topic.)

Comment: Oh lord. I have no idea what I have got me into.. This seems like it got bigger trouble than I actually think. but you are right. I misunderstood between function and method and I know now that I have a function that I need to get deal with. so going from there. Assume I have now this issue with function. I dont think I would be able to use threading for a function now in my case? What I just wanted to do is that I wanted to speed up the sending to `if test in old_list:` where each thread will do `def get_info(thread):` and then send it back to the  `if test in old_list:` and see if its fits..

Comment: The most complicated part of any multithreading or multiprocessing system is that now, instead of a single thread-of-control ("do a; then do b; then if X do C else D") you have multiple different threads-of-control ("hey Joe: do a, then b, then if X do C else D! Meanwhile, Bob: do e, then if Joe did C because of X, do F else G!"). These separate threads-of-control may, as in this example, need to refer to *each other*. But Bob has to wait for Joe to *get* to that point, where Joe tests X, unless Bob can test X before Joe gets there.

Comment: *Reasoning about* multithreaded systems is hard, even once you get all the details of different ways to synchronize them down. When using threads rather than processes, you have to synchronize *all* accesses to any global data; only per-thread data are (generally) safe from interference from other threads. Using separate processes avoids that, but now instead of dealing with interference, you must *transmit* values from one worker to another. Think of threads as many workers in one room, and processes as many workers each in a separate building, and you'll have a good framework for this.

Comment: Im really trying to understand all this but it sounds like I am at 1% of knowing the thread actually haha. I mean I have sit and really tried almost everything and I might just end up not having any threads and just loop through the for loop and do it slowly. It does sounds like a quitter but I am just so exhusted and now all this information made my brain mindblown! haha. But is there a way you could maybe give me an example out of the code that I have wrote at the beginning where I can atleast know where I should think and where I can improve from your point?

Comment: There's too much I don't understand in your original question. For instance, what are these `json.loads` doing? `json.loads` scans a string, if you mean the default json one gets with `import json`, which isn't in your example code, but the `thread` argument isn't a string. Usually people use threads to, e.g., get four or five workers to do simultaneous access to four or five different web sites, collecting data from all of them in parallel. Then either one waits for all data, or one scans each set-of-data as they arrive to see if it's OK to tell the remaining workers to quit early, etc.

Comment: Yeah that sounds something I would do in the future. So im my case the json.loads would be in the future a json file or json read from a URL that contains json when accessing the webpage. And from there my plan was to "scrape" the jsons and return them all into a metadata where I later on compare with `if test in old_list:` - So my idea was that ` for thread in new_list:` every thread contains a URL and with the URL I want to pass it to `get_info` which is gonna scrape and later on do the `if test in old_list` and then repeat wheneverthere is any changes on the json basically.